# Can't boot into Ubuntu after installation failed

Tags: 12.04, installation, updates

Yesterday, I installed the new version of Ubuntu (12.04) but in the middle of the installation, it gave me an error and didn't install the rest.

When I restarted my computer, I booted into Ubuntu, but it didn't do anything – just went black.

I restarted my computer again, and when I tried to uninstall Ubuntu (with Windows Vista) the same happened. It did not work. I tried to just delete it or use CCleaner, but it didn't work either.

Comment: You know what would be great? If instead of "It doesn't work" you would mention the specific error messages you received during installation. What about deleting it or using CCleaner "didn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

If the installation doesn't complete correctly, then it is quite obvious you will get a black screen at boot.

I had a similar issue when installing 12.04. It turned out to be the USB stick which I had been using to install ubuntu on a number of machines.

Recreating the USB stick following the steps mentionned on the official ubuntu site solved the problem for me:

- Ubuntu: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu
- Windows: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

So if you've been using a USB stick, I would suggest to recreate it (and don't manually add any files to it). Hope it'll work for you.